# C++ String not displaying in console

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile an application that uses a string but I don't get the expected result and I receive no error from the compiler. It only happens when I create a string, so if I remove the line that creates a string and cout plain text it works correctly.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string myString = "Hello, this is a string";
    std::cout << myString;
    return 0;
}
```

I then run g++ test.cpp -o test and then ./test.exe and nothing displays on the screen, it just hangs when I expected "Hello, this is a string" to appear. What am I doing wrong..?

**Edit:**
I've disabled avast and the problem still persists.

Comment: Try following `std::cout << myString << std::endl;

Comment: Try disabling any antivirus that's running

Comment: @tchelidze: flushing the console streams is unnecessary, they are auto-flushed

Comment: "C++ String not compiling" - don't lie in the title.

Comment: > `g++ test.cpp -o test` and then `./test.exe` -- why not just `./test`? Or are you running under Windows and I don't know the details of how `g++` works under this platform?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan when is buffer auto-flushed ?

Comment: @tchelidze On program exit.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Thanks, i did not know that ))